# Проблема с inline меню в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

При нажатии на любую кнопку из inline меню срабатыватывает не та, которая нужна, а срабатывают все так как на всех кнопках появляются часики. Как это исправить?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["leagues"])
async def process_leagues(message: types.Message):
    leagues = [("Премьер-лига", "premier_league"), ("Бундеслига", "bundesliga"), ("Бундеслига-2", "bundesliga-2"), ("Чемпионшип", "championship")]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for league, league_cd in leagues:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(league, callback_data="prefix:league_cd"))
    await message.answer("Лиги", reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени это

```
callback_data="prefix:league_cd"
```

На это

```
callback_data=f"prefix:{league_cd}"
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте отформатировать

@dp.message_handler(commands=["leagues"])
async def process_leagues(message: types.Message):
leagues = [("Премьер-лига", "premier_league"), ("Бундеслига", "bundesliga"), ("Бундеслига-2", "bundesliga-2"), ("Чемпионшип", "championship")]
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for league, league_cd in leagues:
markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(league, callback_data=f"{prefix:league_cd}"))
await message.answer("Лиги", reply_markup=markup)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]